# where to host login verification database for android app

Tags: android, database

i'm building an android app for my FYP, that requires a user to signup and subsequently log in.i know i have to build an SQLite database for this,but i don't know where to host the database.The app is to be used on more than one device.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow try [Google Play Game Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/).

It may be not answering your question, but it's my best guess as your question is far from been clear.

In future try to ask more specific questions, show us what you done, and always Google your question first before asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something with online access i can direct you to : [Parse](http://parse.com)

To create an account, you'll only need to do something like this:

```
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
user.setUserName(TEXT);
password.setPassword(TEXT);
user.signUpInBackground();
```

and to login :

```
ParseUser.login("login", "password", somethingelse);
```

and to access the current user :

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
```

You can see more on the website, it's pretty easy.